# mysqldump generates empty dump from my localhost

Tags: mysql

Good day,

I am trying to generate a dump of mysql db using bash.

I created a sample .sh using this [link](https://simon-davies.name/bash/backing-up-mysql-databases)

```
 #!/bin/bash
 # Database credentials
 user="root"
 password=""
 host="localhost"
 db_name="sampledb"
 # Other options
 backup_path="C:\_backup"
 date=$(date +"%d-%b-%Y")
 # Set default file permissions
 umask 177
 # Dump database into SQL file
 mysqldump --user=$user --password= --host=$host $db_name > $backup_path/$db_name-$date.sql
```

The dump file is created but it with 0kb (empty)

what part of my bash is the problem? (me, first time to create something like this)

**UPDATED CODE**

**UPDATE**

It seems that I need to add mysqldump path in my environment variable since
I am running it in win7.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you run the script in an environment where you can actually see the error messages if any or it's e.g. a cron job that's not configured to save or send them anywhere?

Comment: I run it using git bash.

Comment: Alright... What do you get it you literally use `user="doesnotexist"`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the problem is coming from your password ?
I think that you should try to save it in a $password = ""

Answer (score 0):

You are using a bash script (so presumably some flavour of linux/unix) but a Windows path, are you in cygwin? Even on cygwin you need a shebang at the top of the script (#!/bin/bash). Anyway you haven't added the password variable to the command line (or populated it, but I guess that's deliberate), try:

```
mysqldump --user=$user --password=$password --host=$host $db_name > $backup_path/$db_name-$date.sql
```

Your umask variable isn't doing anything. Using a password in a file like this can be insecure, make sure you have restricted access to the file to appropriate users.

Comment: i'm using git bash.
one of article that i've read is about the password of the localhost as being null/none.

Comment: If you haven't set the password for the root user you do not need  `--password` in your mysqldump call. However you **REALLY** should set your root password and use a non-root user in this instance.